# Solr 4 new style solr.xml - how to configure access to core admin pages?

Tags: web, solr, admin

In solr [wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) this phrase can be found:

> To enable dynamic core configuration, make sure the **adminPath** attribute is set in solr.xml. If this attribute is absent, the CoreAdminHandler will not be available.

In old style **solr.xml** this attribute sets in cores element:

> cores adminPath="/admin/cores"

In new (discovery) style **solr.xml** (available since solr 4.4 and mandatory since coming 5th) there is no cores element to set and no any notion about **adminPath** attribute around. As a result, if to check localhost:8983/solr, error occurs:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?wt=json&indexInfo=false
```

Does all this mean dynamic core handling via HTTP is unavailable in 4.4+ solr or I missed to set something in configs?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** solr.xml

```xml
<solr>
    <str name="adminHandler">${adminHandler:org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler}</str>
    <int name="coreLoadThreads">${coreLoadThreads:3}</int>
    <str name="coreRootDirectory">${coreRootDirectory:@SOLR.CORES.DIRECTORY@}</str>
    <str name="managementPath">${managementPath:}</str>
    <str name="sharedLib">${sharedLib:}</str>
    <str name="shareSchema">${shareSchema:false}</str>

    <solrcloud>
        <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdTimeout:1000000}</int>
        <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateTimeout:1000000}</int>
        <int name="leaderVoteWait">${leaderVoteWait:1000000}</int>
        <str name="host">${host:}</str>
        <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
        <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
        <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
    </solrcloud>

    <logging>
        <str name="class">${loggingClass:}</str>
        <str name="enabled">${loggingEnabled:}</str>
        <watcher>
            <int name="size">${loggingSize:1000000}</int>
            <int name="threshold">${loggingThreshold:100000}</int>
        </watcher>
    </logging>
</solr>
```

Comment: Would you share you solr.xml?

Comment: [here](https://copy.com/pMMPInvn8UzB)

Comment: One update: I tested samples (multicore, solr with new style solr.xml), they were all shown up in admin page fine. I use maven to start solr. For old style it worked perfectly, but for new style - admin page keeps failing despite I followed all config amendments described in docs. I'll investigate further. But I think it's fair to close this question as too specific to particular solr launch manner...